# Does React useState's setter ever get stale?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using global event handlers. To avoid detaching/reattaching the event handlers every time the state changes, I'm using a ref with forced updates:

```
  const ref = useRef();
  const forceUpdate = useState()[1];

  const handlePopState = (event) => {
    ref.current = {
      ...ref.current,
      foo: event.foo,
    };
    forceUpdate();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('popstate', handlePopState);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('popstate', handlePopState);
    };
  }, []);
```

I was surprised this actually works. Technically, `forceUpdate` is using a stale version of `useState`'s setter, but that doesn't seem to cause errors.

Is it safe to use a stale version of `useState` like this? If not, what issues could this cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it safe to use a stale version of `useState` like this?

Yes, this is how you you implement `this.forceUpdate` with hooks.

Typically you will see something like:

```
// forceRender();
const [, forceRender] = useReducer((p) => !p, false);
```

Its even used in [`react-redux` source code](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/c581d480dd675f2645851fb006bef91aeb6ac24d/src/hooks/useSelector.js#L15).